# JSON and XML Wrapper for Parsing in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, json

I have seen that most data in iOS is in either JSON or XML. I was interested to know whether there is any third party library or wrapper class that tackles both types of data and responses accordingly. I know I could use for example JSONKit for JSON data and NSXMLParser for XML. But i looking for one that tackles both.

Is there any such wrapper?

Welcome to any suggestions and guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think It's support to JSON /XML,just can you change some line.

```
    NSString *str1=@"type url";
    NSString *poststr1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str1];
    NSString *posturl1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" your url json/xml"];
    // NSLog(@"city url name %@",posturl1);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",posturl1]];
    NSData *postData1 = [poststr1 dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData1 length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData1];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
   // NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//this line supprted to json

    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];//this line supported to xml 
    NSLog(@"json %@",json);
    //NSDictionary*results = [data JSONValue];//this line supported to JSON
    //NSLog(@"results json----->%@",results);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking will do both, and has a goot reputation, for example see the [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21987/top-10-most-useful-ios-libraries-to-know-and-love) site which has lots of other useful information too.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one wrapper class for json. In there, I have created one method given below, I think it will help you.

**Parse Method:**

```
    -(void)jsonDeserialize:(NSString *)key fromDict:(id)content completionHandler:(void (^) (id parsedData, NSDictionary *fromDict))completionHandler{
    if (key==nil && content ==nil) {
        completionHandler(nil,nil);
    }
    if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSDictionary *obj in content) {
          [self jsonDeserialize:key fromDict:obj completionHandler:completionHandler];
        }
    }
    if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        id result = [content objectForKey:key];
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || result == nil) {
            NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)content;
            NSArray *keys = [temp allKeys];
            for (NSString *ikey in keys) {
             [self jsonDeserialize:key fromDict:[content objectForKey:ikey] completionHandler:completionHandler];
            }
        }else{
            completionHandler(result,content);
        }
    }
}
```

**Method Call:**

```
 NSData *content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"json"]];
    NSError *error;
```

> //to get serialized json data...

```
   id dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

> //get data for key called *GetInfo*

```
     [self jsonDeserialize:@"GetInfo" fromDict:dictionary completionHandler:^(id parsedData, NSDictionary *fromDict) {
            NSLog(@"%@ - %@",parsedData,fromDict);
        }];
```